# How to plot time in a range in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a dataframe df as

```
Time           Day
2:03:00 AM     Wed
2:02:00 AM     Wed
1:56:00 AM     Mon
1:54:00 AM     Tue
1:53:00 AM     Mon
1:51:00 AM     Sun
1:51:00 AM     Sun
1:50:00 AM     Sun
1:48:00 AM     Sun
```

I want to plot a graph where I can plot the time in a range like 12am-2am, 2am-4am, and so on vs day

Please help.

Comment: Is your data in reverse time order?

Comment: What are the values you want to plot? Do you have multiple values in each time range?

Comment: @KasperVanLombeek Yes it has multiple values as the day of the week..Sorry for not stating the question clearly..updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is essentially what you are after

```
data <- data.frame(Time=c("2:03:00 AM", "2:02:00 AM", "1:56:00 AM", "1:54:00 AM", "1:53:00 AM", "1:51:00 AM", "1:51:00 AM", "1:50:00 AM", "1:48:00 AM"), 
                   Day=c("Wed", "Wed", "Mon", "Tue", "Mon", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun")) 
data$Day <- factor(data$Day,levels=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"))
data2 <- strptime(paste(data$Time, as.numeric(data$Day), data$Day,sep=" "), format="%H:%M:%S %p %d %a")
hist(data2, breaks="hours", start.on.monday=TRUE, format="%H:%M:%S %p %d")
```